# colorBin() leaflet in R not working as expected

Tags: r, leaflet, r-leaflet, reproducible-research

I have a `data.frame` with two (2) rows in it. I am trying to map this data with colors using the `colorBin` function from `leaflet`

```
my_data <- data.frame("11772","8600000US11772","11772","41957005","1150010","Patchogue","Suffolk","195")
my_data2 <- data.frame("11933","8600000US11933","11933","71811983","6255304","Calverton","Suffolk","1")
names(my_data) <- c("ZipCode", "AFFGEOID10", "GEOID10","ALAND10","AWATER10","City","County","dsch_count")
names(my_data2) <- c("ZipCode", "AFFGEOID10", "GEOID10","ALAND10","AWATER10","City","County","dsch_count")
df <- rbind(my_data, my_data2)
dsch_count_shp <- sp::merge(
  x = usa
  , y = df
  , all.x = F
)


# Test Map
sv_lng <- -72.97659
sv_lat <- 40.78007
sv_zoom <- 9

pal <- colorBin(
  #palette = "BuPu"
  palette = "Dark2"
  , domain = dsch_count_by_city$dsch_count
  , bins = 6
  , reverse = FALSE
)

popup <- paste(
  "<strong>County: </strong>"
  , dsch_count_shp$County
  , "<br><strong>City: </strong>"
  , dsch_count_shp$City
  , "<br><strong>Bin: </strong>"
  , dsch_count_shp$dsch_bin_test
  , "<br><strong>Discharges: </strong>"
  , dsch_count_shp$dsch_count
)

l <- leaflet(data = dsch_count_shp) %>%
  setView(lng = sv_lng, lat = sv_lat, zoom = sv_zoom) %>%
  addTiles(group = "OSM (default)") %>%
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
  addPolygons(
    data = dsch_count_shp
    , fillColor = ~pal(as.numeric(dsch_count_by_city$dsch_count))
    , fillOpacity = 1
    , color = "#BDBDC3"
    , weight = 0.7
    , popup = popup
    ) %>%
  addLayersControl(
    baseGroups = c("OSM (default)", "CartoDB.Positron")
    , options = layersControlOptions(
        collapsed = FALSE
        , position = "topright"
      )
    ) %>%
  addLegend(
    "topright"
    , pal = pal
    , values = ~dsch_count_by_city$dsch_count
    , title = "Discharge Bin"
    , opacity = 1
  )

l
```

Even though the cities have distinct bins[image: Image with color bins]

I keep getting the wrong colors on the map. The shape file is fine I downloaded it from the US Census, not understanding why my bins are not being color mapped correctly.

If I need to upload my dsch_count_by_city and dsch_count_shp as files I can try to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed my problem by doing the following:

```
pal <- colorBin(
  #palette = "BuPu"
  palette = "Dark2"
  #, domain = dsch_count_by_city$dsch_count
  , domain = dsch_count_shp$dsch_count
  , bins = 5
  , reverse = TRUE
)

popup <- paste(
  "<strong>County: </strong>"
  , dsch_count_shp$County
  , "<br><strong>City: </strong>"
  , dsch_count_shp$City
  # , "<br><strong>Bin: </strong>"
  # , dsch_count_shp$dsch_bin_test
  , "<br><strong>Discharges: </strong>"
  , dsch_count_shp$dsch_count
)

l <- leaflet(data = dsch_count_shp) %>%
  setView(lng = sv_lng, lat = sv_lat, zoom = sv_zoom) %>%
  addTiles(group = "OSM (default)") %>%
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
  addPolygons(
    data = dsch_count_shp
    #, fillColor = ~pal(dsch_count_by_city$dsch_count)
    , fillColor = ~pal(dsch_count)
    , fillOpacity = 0.7
    # , color = "#BDBDC3"
    , weight = 0.7
    , popup = popup
    ) %>%
  addLayersControl(
    baseGroups = c("OSM (default)", "CartoDB.Positron")
    , options = layersControlOptions(
        collapsed = FALSE
        , position = "topright"
      )
    ) %>%
  addLegend(
    "topright"
    , pal = pal
    #, values = ~dsch_count_by_city$dsch_count
    , values = ~dsch_count
    , title = "Discharge Bin"
    , opacity = 1
  )

l
```

Comment: Did you solve your question? I have a question, maybe you can help me. Look:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55475420/exchanging-map-results-using-leaflet-and-state-popup

Comment: I posted what i think may help you

Comment: what is your email? Could I send you my bases for you to evaluate?

Comment: I'll try. Can you push it to github?

Comment: I created an account in github and added the files I'm trying to create a button (checkbox) to change the databases on the map. My User: brunoavilaf. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use this:
customize "bins <- c(0.2, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40)" the numbers according to your data